# how to convert an int to a char C++

Tags: c++

Im having trouble with an assignment where I have to convert three variables of a clock (int hour, int minutes, and bool afternoon) to be converted to a string in a method. I tried converting the int to a char and then replacing each string with the char. The function is suppose to return T/F if the conversion worked or not. Here is what I have so far:

```
class Time
{
private:
  int hour;
  int minutes;
  bool afternoon;
public:
  void setHour(int hr);
  void setMinutes(int min);
  void setAfternoon(bool aft);

  int getHour();
  int getMinutes();
  bool getAfternoon();

  bool setAsString(string time);
  string getAsString();

  Time(void);
  ~Time(void);
};
```

and

```
bool Time::setAsString(string time){
char min = minutes;
char hr = hour;

char hr[0] = time[0];
char hr[1]= time[1];
char min[0] = time[3];
char min[1] = time[4];
char afternoon = time[6];
if ((hourTens > 1) || (minTens > 5)) {
return false;
} else {
return true;
}
}
string Time::getAsString(){
return false;
}
```

Comment: Look up `atoi` and `itoa` functions

Comment: i forgot to mention that my professor prefers we do this without using functions like those. he wants it from scratch

Comment: Let me give you some hints, then: 1) What is `'1' - '0'`? What is `1 + '0'`? 2) `/ 10` divided by 10, `% 10` gets the remainder you'd get from dividing by 10 (e.g. whatever is in the units column) Now you know enough to solve the problem.

Comment: '1' - '0' = '1' and 1 + '0' = ascii code right? and as for the /10, im not sure how this helps me. I am new to c++. would doing this get me any closer to my goal, this is basically what out professor wants (swap a given int (eg. 09) into a given string (eg. 00:00 am), but i dont know exactly how to do it:

`int intday = 15;
string strDay = "00";
char day = intday + '0';
strDay[1] = intDay[1];`

Comment: No.  `'1' - 0` is `'1'` but `'1' - '0'` is different.

Comment: btw, I am a bit confused after reading your question again: are you converting your time "to a string" or are you trying to convert a string to a time?  and... "swap a given int into a given string" ? what does it mean?  Ask your question clearly and don't make up those 'sounds-professional-but-only-known-by-you' terminologies.

Answer (score 14):

it is straight-forward in fact, but may involve a little twist in mind at first.

I am not going to give you the actual code, but some snippet that, if you can understand them, you should be able to solve the problem by yourself:

What you want to do is converting an integer to a string/char.  The most basic thing you need to do is to convert a single digit int to corresponding char.

```
// for example you have such integer
int i = 3;

// and you want to convert it to a char so that
char c = '3';
```

what you need to do is, by adding i to '0'.  The reason why it works is because '0' actually means an integer value of 48.  '1'..'9' means 49..57.  This is a simple addition to find out corresponding character for an single decimal digit integer:

i.e. char c = '0' + i;

If you know how to convert a single decimal digit int to char, what's left is how you can extract individual digit from a more-than-one-decimal-digit integer

it is simply a simple math by making use of / and %

```
int i = 123 % 10;  // give u last digit, which is 3
int j = 123 / 10;  // give remove the last digit, which is 12
```

The logic left is the homework you need to do then.

Comment: thankyou so much, i have been fiddling with this all week. for anyone else who finds this, I just did the following:

`string time = "00:00;
int minutes = 15;
int tensMin = minutes / 10;// to get the tens digit of the minutes
int onesMin = minutes % 10;// to get the ones digit of the minutes
char tens = tensMin;
char ones = onesMin;
time[0] = tensMin;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to manually convert each char into an int, here is a very rough idea. Use a `switch` statement to convert each char into its ascii value. For example, `switch(char_to_convert)`'s `case 38` would return 1. Basically, "1" converted to ASCII is 49(Thank you Ben Voigt for the correction). You don't actually need to convert it; you compiler will notice and convert it for you. **Then** you make the comparisons. See Ascii Table for a complete list.